# How to deal with error port 80: Operation timed out when scraping website?

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I am attempting to scrape presidential speeches from the website of the Russian Federation. Here is the code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

get_speech = function(speech_link) {
  speech_page = read_html(speech_link)
  speech_name_full = speech_page %>% html_nodes(".p-name") %>% html_text()
  speech_published = speech_page %>% html_nodes(".read__published") %>% html_text()
  speech_text_list = speech_page %>% html_nodes(".read__internal_content > p") %>% html_text()
  speech_text_merged_n = speech_text_list %>% paste(collapse = "\n")
  speech_text = gsub("\n", " ", speech_text_merged_n)
  speech_filename = substr(speech_name_full, 1, 200)
  filename_unclean = paste0(speech_published, " - ", speech_filename, ".txt")
  filename = str_remove_all(filename_unclean, "[/>+'|=_?;:<}{!@#$%^&*()]")
  write.table(
    speech_text_list,
    file = filename,
    row.names = FALSE,
    col.names = FALSE,
    append = FALSE,
    quote = FALSE,
    eol = "\r\r"
  )
  random_number = runif(1, 1.5, 3)
  Sys.sleep(random_number)
  return(speech_text)
}

for (page_result in seq(from = 1, to = 21, by = 1)) {
  link = paste0("http://www.kremlin.ru/events/president/transcripts/page/", page_result)
  page = read_html(link)
  
  name = page %>% html_nodes(".p-name") %>% html_text()
  speech_links = page %>% html_nodes(".hentry__title_special a") %>% html_attr("href") %>%
    paste("http://kremlin.ru", .,sep = "")
  meta = page %>% html_nodes(".hentry__meta") %>% html_text()
  date_spaces = sub(" года.*", "", meta)
  date = substring(date_spaces, 3)
  location_spaces = sub(".*сайта Президента России", "", meta)
  location = substring(location_spaces, 2)
  text = sapply(speech_links, FUN = get_speech)
  everything = rbind(everything, data.frame(name, date, location, text, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  print (paste("Page:", page_result))
  
  random_number = runif(1, 1.5, 3)
  Sys.sleep(random_number)
}
```

When I run this code, I receive the following error: `Error in open.connection(x, "rb") :  Failed to connect to www.kremlin.ru port 80: Operation timed out`. Any advice on how to modify the code in order to prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: _You_ cannot necessarily prevent the error, it's a factor of many things that are out of your control. It could be caused by: your firewall; your wireless router; your ISP; the remote web-server or rev-proxy/load-balancer(s); any network segment between your ISP and the remote web-server/rev-proxy/load-balancers. If you are able to make other connections while this one times out, then it is unlikely any of the first three. The best you can do is `tryCatch` it, looking for the timeout, and handle that condition gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

In general, *you* cannot necessarily prevent the error, as it can be due to many things outside of your control and even your awareness. It could be due to:

- your firewall and/or OS's network stack
- your wireless router and/or internal router(s)
- your ISP
- any network segment between your ISP and the remote's ISP
- the ISP of the remote end
- any of the networking components of the remote
- the rev-proxy/load-balancer/web-server of the remote

If you are able to make other connections while this one times out, then it is unlikely to be any of the first three on this list. You might be able to isolate "where" it might be occurring by using OS-level tools (not R) such as `traceroute`.

(I'm assuming DNS is not a factor here.)

The best you can do in R is to try to catch this exception (`tryCatch` or `try` in base R) and handle it gracefully.